# Use output from command line as a parameter for a command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace a command with the result of another in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/398188/how-to-replace-a-command-with-the-result-of-another-in-linux)

I'm able to parse my command output so it only shows the file name that I'm interested.

My question is, I want to be able to take the output and use it as a parameter for `svn diff`.

```
svn diff /filename_from_output/
```

Comment: set the filename from output to a variable and pass that variable in to your command.  foo = `some command`; some_other_command $foo;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, the following should work:

```
svn diff "$(your-command)"
```

`$()` is simple bash [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). The output of the command enclosed in `$()` will be substituted in the outer command.

Answer (score 0):

I usually enclose the command in backquotes.  This works in tcsh too...  I am just used to doing it this way because I write a bit of Perl.

```
svn diff `whatname.sh`
```

Or if the output can contain spaces:

```
svn diff "`whatname.sh`"
```