# Cygwin convert windows path to unix then change dir

Tags: cygwin

I am usually trying to use the cygwin terminal to move to a nested directory. The problem is the windows directory are not immediately interpreted.

So I had to do two step:

```
$ cygpath -u "C:\Develop\blah\blah\blah\too_deep\"
/cygdrive/c/Develop/blah/blah/blah/too_deep/
$ cd /cygdrive/c/Develop/blah/blah/blah/too_deep/
```

I need to convert the path first then paste the result to change it.

I tried to use redirect but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
$ cygpath -u "C:\Develop\blah\blah\blah\too_deep\" | cd
```

=> No results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use output from command line as a parameter for a command](https://superuser.com/questions/413567/use-output-from-command-line-as-a-parameter-for-a-command)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

> cd $(cygpath -u 'C:\Develop\blah\blah\blah\too_deep\')

The $(command) construct does a command substitution and is replaced with the output of the command.

Answer (score 14):

You'll need to enclose it in double quotes if the path contains spaces:

```
cd "$(cygpath -u 'c:\Program Files\')"
```

Comment: You repeat the old answer!

Comment: actually, not quite. He's enclosed that with double quotes. Not sure if it'll work, but it does seem marginally unique

Comment: Confirmed as working. However so does the version without double quotes as per the accepted answer.

Comment: When I test previous version:

`$ cd $(cygpath -u 'c:\Program Files\')`

I met the error message: -bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

or simple old fashioned

```
cd `cygpath --unix "C:\Develop\blah\blah\blah\too_deep\ "`
```

Please note the space after the last backslash.